# How to close a prompt form or dialogue upon a hardware event?

Tags: delphi

I want to prompt the user to scan a bar code or RFID tag. That (I guess) means either MessageDlg() or a small form - I don't care which and invite advice.

When I read a scan over serial port or HID (or timer or WM_xxxx), I want to close that prompt.

What is the simplest way to go about that?  Thankls

Comment: You can show your form using `ShowModal` and after you'll be done with scanning set the `ModalResult` of that form to something else than 0.

Comment: Readers allow to add a custom character at the end of the data, so it is easy to simulate a `<Enter>` key

Comment: downvote? Someone doesn't like RFID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have this feature in our application with even 1 more integrated step to start with.
I will describe it fully, as it might be useful to you.

We have a modal dialog that allows the user to enter the Serial Id for a device by either keying it in with the keyboard or just scanning the barcode tag.

Step 1. We have a menu item with a Hot Key (Shortcut Ctrl+Alt+N for instance). We have configured the scanner so that it sends this preamble whenever it scans a barcode. (Manual equivalent of keying in the shortcut). That opens the modal dialog.

Step 2. The Focus is in a Edit box to get the Serial ID either from the user and the keyboard or from the scanner reading the barcode.

Step 3. There are an [OK] and a [Cancel] buttons. The OK button has `Default:=True` and `ModalResult:=mrOK`. The Cancel button has `Cancel:=True` and `ModalResult:=mrCancel`. The scanner is set to postfix the scanned string with Enter which has the same effect as the user hitting the [Enter] key or clicking the OK button: it closes the modal dialog with mrOK in the ModalResult so we can read the Edit.text to get the SerialID.

Step 3bis. The user presses [Esc] or click on Cancel or closes the dialog with the title bar close button: it closes the dialog with anything but `mrOK` and we discard whatever is in the Edit...

Works very well in our case with any scanner working as an HID emulation (keyboard) and where we can configure the preamble. (sending Enter at the end was by default in all the scanners we tried).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a form, making it without border and title (or no close button) and stayontop and add in your message or animation or anything.  If applicable, it is best to give a cancel button for the user to cancel the operation.

You can create the form the first time you use it and check for Assigned to free it on your parent form close.

Then when you need the user to scan card (or the like), just

1. Lock your parent form for other input then the those you expected,
2. show the form (not showmodel) and loop / wait for the event in your parent form.
3. You can still process other functionality if needed, but be very careful as unexpected action might mess up the operation.
4. when condition met (success scan or canceled or time out, etc), hide the child form
5. unlock your parent form and proceed.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan In my own cases, ShowModal is easier and less problematic, but not necessary better.  Using show, your parent form still have full control and one can keep some functionality of the parent form available if needed.  I agreed that if the operation is as simple as scan or fail, then ShowModal is easier to implement.

Comment: How do you close a modal form from a main form event handler?  Post it a WM_CLOSE?

Comment: @MartinJames I am suggesting not using ShowModel in my answer so that main form can have full control and the program logic also in the main form.  If using ShowModal as suggested by David & TLama, I think the control is in the model form.

Comment: @MartinJames: You set its `ModalResult` to something other than `mrNone` (or 0), like `mrCancel` or `mrOK` (depending upon whether you are closing it on time out or upon an expected hardware event).